# When should colour and colouring tags be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags: `colour` and `colouring`.

Now I realize that when the question is about how to deal with colours, `colouring` tag will not be appropriate.

`colouring` will be appropriate where people are applying colours to a medium.
`colour` tag will be appropriate where people ask about how to deal with the colours themselves rather than how to apply them.

But, will the `colour` tag be appropriate where people ask about how to apply colour to a medium, along with the `colouring` tag?

Example: [How do you fade one color to another with oil paint without getting the mixed color?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-do-you-fade-one-color-to-another-with-oil-paint-without-getting-the-mixed-co)

Are `colour` and `colouring` tags both appropriate here at the same time?

Comment: As a note, SE is generally US spelling centric so the tags should be color and coloring.

Comment: @catija is there a policy regarding that mentioned somewhere?

Comment: Yes. : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/284336

Comment: @catija thanks. Will change the spelling soon.

Comment: Please don't edit questions so significantly after many answers, especially when it's essentially invalidates existing ones and poses a new question. If you need to update everyone who answered, it's too extreme.

Comment: @CreationEdge  I understand your point t but this question body is meaningless without this edit. I had totally forgotten about explicitly mentioning drawing g and painting here and then I was wondering why people are finding it so broad. :::::::: do you suggest I open another question for the said changes?

Comment: Making major changes to questions after they have been answered is extremely bad form. It often invalidates the answers. Please roll this back to the original form and ask a new question if you have a new question to ask.

Comment: Yes. Your original question was about general policy on the tags. Your new question incorporates an answer here as if it's policy, but we're still deciding that.

Comment: @CreationEdge done , will ask a separate question  now.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Beofett a little, I think [color](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) is generally too broad and doesn't speak to the medium.

However, I think it's fine to have as long as we moderate it's usage. For instance, if we want to have questions such as [Reliably identify the local color of a subject in non-white light?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/239/how-can-i-reliably-identify-the-local-color-of-a-subject-non-white-light) . There's not really a more fitting tag than [color](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) that I can think of at the moment.

If the question is really about mixing colors, then I feel [color-mixing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-mixing) would be better suited. This allows experts and knew users to combine the tag with their medium, and provide info or learn it.

Comment: What about questions about color theory? Is that something that would get a lot of play here, you think?

Comment: @Catija That's a good question. That may be more appropriate than "color" in the example I provided.

Comment: I know DVs are anonymous, but as it stands, we have 3 varying answers, all with -1, and no alternate suggestions that people are agreeing on. If you're downvoting, *please* consider posting your own answer.

Comment: Or at least explain **why** you are DVing.

Comment: I like [tag:color-mixing].  But I don't understand your example of "how do I reliably find the local color...?".  Wouldn't that be for a specific medium?  It may just be that I'm not familiar enough with the topic, because I don't know what "local color" means.

Comment: @Beofett See update to answer, it has a link.

Comment: @CreationEdge Thanks.  That's a great case for a color tag.  +1 from me.

Comment: Please see the changes in question

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using [colouring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colouring) for applying colors to a medium.  That is too generic, and instead the type of pigments should be the tag (e.g. [pencils](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencils), [oil-paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-paint), [acrylics](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acrylics), [markers](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markers)).

**If** we need a tag for "coloring" (note we'd have to have synonyms for both variants of spelling), I'd argue that it should only be for using colored pencils, markers, or crayons to fill in outlined black-and-white images (which has become a very popular hobby lately).

Comment: Please see the changes in question

Answer (score 0):

[color](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) should only be used when asking about the selection or mechanics of specific pigments (such as your example).

Comment: "Coloring" *is* the name of a specific activity, as you suggested, related to the mediums you suggested. There's another context when "coloring" is a noun, but I don't see why that wouldn't fit better under a different tag. Would you consider making your coloring answer separate, so we can see how the community feels about it outside of being tied to your "color" answer?

Comment: @CreationEdge Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that works great. The "coloring" one does seem to be better received.