# Should pencil-shading be broken up into two tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[pencil-shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-shading) has been gaining some ground. A recent question [How can I do the hatching shading technique properly?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/446/how-can-i-do-the-hatching-shading-technique-properly) uses the tag, however, the content of the question talks about ink based shading as well.

> I really like the hatching technique especially with pens, or 'calligraphy pens'

So if the perceived focus was pencil-shading the op might get more specific answers that were not being sought after. If he tried to add just [shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shading) it would have offered [pencil-shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-shading).

I propose that these tags are split so that [shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shading) can be associated to the specific tools *if need be*. In the case of the above question I would think the tags should be [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) and [shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shading) since the implement is not necessarily the focus.

Comment: Yeah, this is something we really need to hash out in general... separating techniques from media... Do we want to clump all types of "shading" into one tag and then use media tags to differentiate, or do we want to have tags specific to each... which could be a ton of very rarely-used tags.

Comment: We have a question about coloring which is essentially the same type of thing. I'll write up something tonight, but in general I'm against all these technique tags. Medium and art field, such as pencils and drawing, should suffice.

Comment: Might be worth making this into a broader discussion...

Comment: I don't like the idea of `ink-shading`. I suppose the `shading`s would be finite but I am sure that there are things there share so `shading` on its own feels right.

Comment: @Catija What do you propose the scope to be? implement and technique tags vs implement-technique tags? I would worry it would be too broad.

Comment: @CreationEdge Did we just find our "character tags" discussion/argument???  :P

Comment: Sometimes broad meta topics are good... particularly when it comes to tags... Not implement, though... media and technique... charcoal shading, for example, charcoal is a medium... or watercolor shading. It's not about charcoal pencils or paintbrushes, it's about the medium used. The correct implement is potentially part of the solution, not the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt to answer this on a broader scale, so it should still fit if the question is edited.

---

Currently, one of our top tags is [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique). However, when I look at those questions I don't see the tag actually adding any value to the question. Most questions we already have about actually *doing* the art could qualify for [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique), but many of them *don't* have it.

If we applied it every question that was asking about the way to do things, [technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) we'd certainly be our top tag, without telling us much about the rest of the question. It's too broad, can be combined with almost any other tag, and *needs* to be combined with another tag to make any sense.

**[technique](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) should be removed and similar tags avoided.** We've taken similar steps for other tags, such as [tools](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/78/), which were overly broad and not helpful in the end.

---

In this case, that would leave us with [pencil](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil) + [drawing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) + [shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shading) vs [pencil-shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-shading) (possibly + [drawing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing)). Since the single tag [pencil-shading](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-shading) conveys all the necessary information in one go, and is a distinct skill set from drawing alone, I think **it should be used instead of a combination of other tags**.

Similar concepts will come up, such as [coloring](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/74/) and [tools](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/78/) and [maintenance](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/is-maintenance-really-tool-maintenance/111#111), where **a "parent" tag about the medium/implement should suffice, unless the more specific tag represents a distinct set of skills and expertise** and stands well on its own.

Comment: What about shading questions that are generic and don't apply to a specific media?

Comment: @Matt In that case, such as general questions about "paint", it seems fine. For instance, a cross-hatching question that's not just about *pencils*, how else would you tag it? The same as `color`, [which has been brought up in meta before](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/a/81/24).